# How do I update this Text Box's text in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, stopwatch

So I am making a stopwatch in python with tkinter,  I have the loop for updating the time working, but I have it so the loop clears the text box, and then updates the text box with the new number.

Although it doesnt work, for some reason it just doesnt clear it, it just keeps adding numbers to the box.

Here is the code that I have used, if someone would be able to have a look at this for me I would appriciate it a lot :)

```
import time
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("StopWatch")

#textbox for the screen
screen = Text(root, height = 1, width = 20, bd=10)
screen.grid(row=0, column=0)

#Active variable
global stopwatch_active
stopwatch_active = False
stop_time = 0
stop_minutes = 0


#command for starting the stopwatch
def start_com():
    stop_btn.config(state=NORMAL)
    stopwatch_active = True
    start_btn.config(state=DISABLED)
    global stop_time
    stop_time += 1
    screen.insert(END, stop_time)
    root.after(1000, start_com)




#button for starting the stopwatch
start_btn = Button(root, text = "Start", width = 10, bd = 5, command = start_com)
start_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

#button for stopping the stopwatch
stop_btn = Button(root, text = "Stop", width = 10, bd = 5)
stop_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
stop_btn.config(state=DISABLED)
```

Answer (score 5):

Add:

```
screen.delete("1.0", END)
```

Before you do:

```
screen.insert(END, stop_time)
```

This will clear all the text from the text box. [Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) has more information if your interested. This will produce something similar to:

[image]

Comment: Yes, they work _sometimes_ but they are incorrect usage, and relying on it to work isn't very wise. An index is a string of the form <line>.<character>. Try using a floating point index like `1.10` and you'll see it doesn't work so well, since `1.10` is the same as `1.1` but _not_ the same as `"1.10"`.

Comment: Ah. I've always found tkinter index system a little... different. Using python's indexing with slices would be nicer IMHO.

Comment: Supporting slicing wouldn't be that hard, but you would lose a lot of power. With tkinter indexes you can do things like "insert lineend" or "my_marker+1c", etc.