# Can't get contents of an Entry widget using input()

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write a simple python gui in windows 8.1 using python 3.4.2.
I try to make a program to calculate a  concentration (molarity = moles / liter) but in the GUI I create No answer appears in the Text widget but numbers appear in the command shell.
The calculations also don't seem to work because when I left the entry empty something was calculated (which should be impossible, even if empty Entries would evaluate to 0 it shouldn't be able to divide by 0) and it gives me these numbers `.56494480.56494448`.

I think the problem is in this part

```
def mol(self):
    moli = float(input(self.grammi)) / float(input(self.peso_molecolare))
    self.text.delete(0.0, END)
    self.text(0.0, moli)


def mola(self):
    conc = float(float(input(self.grammi)/ float(input(self.peso_molecolare))) / float(input(self.litri))

    self.text.delete(0.0, END)
    self.text.insert(0.0, conc)
```

If you want the entire code here it is

```
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.instuction = Label(self, text="inserisci i seguenti dati")
        self.instuction.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
        self.grammi = Entry(self)
        self.grammi.label = Label(self, text="grammi")
        self.grammi.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.grammi.label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.peso_molecolare = Entry(self)
        self.peso_molecolare.label = Label(self, text="peso molecolare")
        self.peso_molecolare.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.peso_molecolare.label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.litri = Entry(self, text="litri")
        self.litri.label = Label(self, text="litri")
        self.litri.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.litri.label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.moli_button = Button(self, text="calcolo moli", command=self.mol)
        self.moli_button.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)
        self.conc_button = Button(self, text="concentrazione", command=self.mola)
        self.conc_button.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)
        self.exit_button = Button(self, text="Exit", command=self.close_window)
        self.exit_button.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)

        self.text = Text(self, width=35, height=5, wrap=NONE)
        self.text.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    def mol(self):
        moli = float(input(self.grammi)) / float(input(self.peso_molecolare))
        self.text.delete('1.0', END)
        self.text.insert('1.0', moli)


    def mola(self):
        conc = float(float(input(self.grammi)) / float(input(self.peso_molecolare))) / float(input(self.litri))
        self.text.delete('1.0', END)
        self.text.insert('1.0', conc)

    def close_window(self):
        root.destroy()


root = Tk()
root.title("chimica")
root.geometry("400x200")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you using wxPython?

Comment: Please provide more code and more context. A shot, runnable example with an explanation of what you expect to happen will make your question possible to answer. Also, it looks like you're using Tkinter. If that is true you should tag your question accordingly.

Comment: I have voted to close as "Unclear what you are asking" because you have not improved your question.

Comment: Python 3.4.2 for win in windows 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Tkinter, to get the value inserted in an Entry widget you shouldn't use [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) but you have to use the [`get`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112032001/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.get-method) method like:

```
moli = float(self.grammi.get()) / float(self.peso_molecolare.get())
```

same goes for `conc`:

```
conc = float(self.grammi.get()) / float(self.peso_molecolare.get()) / float(self.litri.get())
```

---

The problem you have is that `input` will prompt for user input in the command shell, after asking the question that is between the parentheses. However, you put a reference to an Entry widget there. So what is printed (`.56494480` and `.56494448`) are internal references to these widgets, not results of any calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I must assume that you are using Tkinter. It might be that line numbers start at 1 and you are inserting at line 0. Also, indexes are strings, not floats.

Try altering your code to:

```
def mol(self):
    moli = float(input(self.grammi)) / float(input(self.peso_molecolare))
    self.text.delete('1.0', END)
    self.text.insert('1.0', moli)

def mola(self):
    conc = float(float(input(self.grammi)) / float(input(self.peso_molecolare))) / float(input(self.litri))
    self.text.delete('1.0', END)
    self.text.insert('1.0', conc)
```

Or you could just use `self.text.insert(INSERT, conc)` which will insert at the current insertion point.

Comment: It seems that Tkinter is more forgiving about indices than documented, but at least now your code is consistent with the documentation. I think that [`fhdrsdg's`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29964452/21945) answer is correct - you need to use `.get()`, not `input()`.

Comment: Although it doesn't solve the problem, you are making a very true observation. Text indexes should be strings, not floats. This has caused [a lot of confusion](https://www.google.nl/search?q=tkinter+text+index+float+site:stackoverflow.com) because they work in some cases, [but fail in a lot more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502418/how-do-i-update-this-text-boxs-text-in-tkinter#comment43439128_27502724).